# Como criar um arquivo de índice utilizando árvore B+

Tags: c, arquivo, ponteiro, índices, árvore

Tenho uma árvore B+ que atua como índice de um arquivo de dados. Este índice deve ser salvo em um arquivo de índices.

A struct `node` ou nó da árvore B+ é:

```
typedef struct node 
{
    void ** pointers;
    int * keys;
    struct node * parent;
    bool is_leaf;
    int num_keys;.
} node;
```

Como guardar este índice feito em árvore B+ em um arquivo, e como posteriormente recuperar o índice para a memória a partir deste mesmo arquivo? Se possível uma implementação deste caso ou um exemplo, para complementar a explicação.

Comment: Poderia dar mais informações dos membros desta estrutura, isto é, sobre que estruturas/tipos os ponteiros estão apontando? Existem outras estruturas envolvidas?

Answer (score 1):

Eu acredito que qualquer arquivo formatado pode fazê-lo, tendo folha dentro de folha e depois implementando seu próprio algoritmo para criar cada objeto separado (você não pretende guardar o registro, certo?). Exemplo: `(!strcmp(objeto.tagName,"tree"))? instancia_hipotetica.is_leaf = false, instancia_hipotetica.is_leaf = true;`. Eu recomendo o sistema DOM ([eXpat](http://expat.sourceforge.net/) - XML).

Edit - pelo o que eu vi, você está usando "chaves" (keys). Com um parser de DOM, você não precisa sequer guardar o número de chaves, o programa calcula pelo numero de tags na subtag. Se não gostar de DOM/XML, você também pode usar JSON.

Answer (score 1):

As árvores B+ foram desenhada para funcionarem em disco.

O uso típico de Árvores B+ contempla possibilidade de enorme quantidade de chaves (ex. milhões), tipicamente ter os nodos todos em ficheiro e só ser carregado para memória as páginas necessárias.

No geral cada página costuma ter tamanho fixo (para permitir mais facilmente calcular o local em disco onde está a página) e os apontadores tendem a ser "números de página", referentes ao ficheiro em disco.

Deste modo convinha:

- rever o tipo "node" de modo a que passe a conter contiguamente a página completa, e com tamanho 
  fixo (exemplo array de pares (chave, números-de-página)).
- converter pointers em números-de-pagina

gravar/carregar página seria algo como

```
offset = tamanho x numeroDePagina
fseek(ficheir,offset, 0)
fread ou fwrite (página, sizeof(node),1 ,ficheiro)
```